# UWP - How to change the size of a drag image during drag and drop?

Tags: uwp, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag and drop a UI element that exists within a Viewbox.  As soon as the drag process begins, the expected image shows up for the drag operation, but the image is full size and not the size of the image as displayed within the Viewbox.

Is there a way to have the drag image automatically respect the displayed size of the source element?  If not, is there a way to programmatically change the size of the drag image to match the displayed size of the of the UI element being dragged?

I don't see any options in the DragStartingEventArgs's DataPackage or DragUI that would allow the drag image to be resized.

The UI element being dragged is a RelativePanel with a number of embedded images and shapes within it.

Comment: For now, there's no built-in APIs for you to do it. You could submit a **Feature Request** on windows 'Feedback Hub'.

Comment: If there is no built-in APIs, is there a suggested workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this is a bit hacky, but it seems to work well.  There is a lot of refining that can be done but here is a way to get it done.

```
    private async void OnDragStarting(UIElement sender, DragStartingEventArgs args)
    {
        var relativePanel = (RelativePanel) sender;
        var ellipse = (Ellipse)relativePanel.Children.ToList()[0];

        var deferral = args.GetDeferral();

        var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await bitmap.RenderAsync(ellipse);

        // convert the ellipse to a pixel array
        var pixelBuffer = await bitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
        var pixelArray = pixelBuffer.ToArray();

        var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

        var img = new BitmapImage();
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
        encoder.SetPixelData(
            BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
            BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
            (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth,
            (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight,
            96,
            96,
            pixelArray);

        // now that there is an encoder set up, set the new size of the image
        encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = 50;
        encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = 50;

        await encoder.FlushAsync();
        await img.SetSourceAsync(stream);

        args.DragUI.SetContentFromBitmapImage(img);

        deferral.Complete();
    }
```